# Python Inspect Module Finding All of Functions

Tags: python

I have written a python script that will show sub modules , classes and functions of os module. I have gotten results and i have tried compare with [this site](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.fspath). I have realized there is functions in the site that is not in output of my code.

My code:

```
import os
import colorama

### getting sub modules ###
print(colorama.Fore.GREEN)
print("Modules :\n")
for modules in inspect.getmembers(os,inspect.ismodule):
    print("os.",modules[0],sep='')
for modules in inspect.getmembers(os.path,inspect.ismodule):
    print("os.path.",modules[0],sep='')
for modules in inspect.getmembers(os.path.genericpath,inspect.ismodule):
    print("os.path.genericpath.",modules[0],sep='')
print(colorama.Fore.WHITE,"\n","-"*50)
### end ###
# ---------- #
# ---------- #
# ---------- #
### getting classes ###
print(colorama.Fore.BLUE)
print("Classes :\n")
for classes in inspect.getmembers(os,inspect.isclass):
    print("os.",classes[0],sep='')
for classes in inspect.getmembers(os.abc,inspect.isclass):
    print("os.abc.",classes[0],sep='')
for classes in inspect.getmembers(os.path.stat,inspect.isclass):
    print("os.path.stat.",classes[0],sep='')
print(colorama.Fore.WHITE,"\n","-"*50)
### end ###
# ---------- #
# ---------- #
# ---------- #
###getting functions ###
print(colorama.Fore.RED)
print("Functions :\n")
for funcs in inspect.getmembers(os,inspect.isfunction):
    print("os.",funcs[0],sep='')
for funcs in inspect.getmembers(os.MutableMapping,inspect.isfunction):
    print("os.MutableMapping.",funcs[0],sep='')
for funcs in inspect.getmembers(os.PathLike,inspect.isfunction):
    print("os.PathLike.",funcs[0],sep='')
for funcs in inspect.getmembers(os._Environ,inspect.isfunction):
    print("os._Environ.",funcs[0],sep='')
for funcs in inspect.getmembers(os._wrap_close,inspect.isfunction):
    print("os._wrap_close.",funcs[0],sep='')
for funcs in inspect.getmembers(os.abc.ABCMeta,inspect.isfunction):
    print("os.abc.ABCMeta.",funcs[0],sep='')
for funcs in inspect.getmembers(os.abc.abstractclassmethod,inspect.isfunction):
    print("os.abc.abstractclassmethod.",funcs[0],sep='')
for funcs in inspect.getmembers(os.abc.abstractstaticmethod,inspect.isfunction):
    print("os.abc.abstractstaticmethod.",funcs[0],sep='')
for funcs in inspect.getmembers(os.path,inspect.isfunction):
    print("os.path.",funcs[0],sep='')
for funcs in inspect.getmembers(os.path.genericpath,inspect.isfunction):
    print("os.path.genericpath.",funcs[0],sep='')
for funcs in inspect.getmembers(os.path.stat,inspect.isfunction):
    print("os.path.stat.",funcs[0],sep='')
for funcs in inspect.getmembers(os.st,inspect.isfunction):
    print("os.sys.",funcs[0],sep='')
### end ###
```

And this is output:

```
Modules :

os.abc
os.path
os.st
os.sys
os.path.genericpath
os.path.os
os.path.stat
os.path.sys
os.path.genericpath.os
os.path.genericpath.stat
 
 --------------------------------------------------

Classes :                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                      
os.DirEntry                                                                                                                                                           
os.MutableMapping                                                                                                                                                     
os.PathLike                                                                                                                                                           
os._Environ                                                                                                                                                           
os._wrap_close                                                                                                                                                        
os.error                                                                                                                                                              
os.sched_param                                                                                                                                                        
os.stat_result                                                                                                                                                        
os.statvfs_result                                                                                                                                                     
os.terminal_size                                                                                                                                                      
os.times_result                                                                                                                                                       
os.uname_result                                                                                                                                                       
os.waitid_result                                                                                                                                                      
os.abc.ABC                                                                                                                                                            
os.abc.ABCMeta                                                                                                                                                        
os.abc.abstractclassmethod                                                                                                                                            
os.abc.abstractproperty                                                                                                                                               
os.abc.abstractstaticmethod                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                      
 --------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                      
Functions :                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                      
os._check_methods                                                                                                                                                     
os._execvpe                                                                                                                                                           
os._exists                                                                                                                                                            
os._fspath                                                                                                                                                            
os._fwalk                                                                                                                                                             
os._get_exports_list                                                                                                                                                  
os._spawnvef                                                                                                                                                          
os.execl                                                                                                                                                              
os.execle                                                                                                                                                             
os.execlp                                                                                                                                                             
os.execlpe                                                                                                                                                            
os.execvp                                                                                                                                                             
os.execvpe                                                                                                                                                            
os.fdopen                                                                                                                                                             
os.fsdecode                                                                                                                                                           
os.fsencode                                                                                                                                                           
os.fwalk                                                                                                                                                              
os.get_exec_path                                                                                                                                                      
os.getenv                                                                                                                                                             
os.getenvb                                                                                                                                                            
os.makedirs                                                                                                                                                           
os.popen                                                                                                                                                              
os.removedirs                                                                                                                                                         
os.renames                                                                                                                                                            
os.spawnl                                                                                                                                                             
os.spawnle                                                                                                                                                            
os.spawnlp                                                                                                                                                            
os.spawnlpe                                                                                                                                                           
os.spawnv                                                                                                                                                             
os.spawnve                                                                                                                                                            
os.spawnvp                                                                                                                                                            
os.spawnvpe                                                                                                                                                           
os.walk                                                                                                                                                               
os.MutableMapping.__contains__                                                                                                                                        
os.MutableMapping.__delitem__                                                                                                                                         
os.MutableMapping.__eq__                                                                                                                                              
os.MutableMapping.__getitem__                                                                                                                                         
os.MutableMapping.__iter__                                                                                                                                            
os.MutableMapping.__len__                                                                                                                                             
os.MutableMapping.__setitem__                                                                                                                                         
os.MutableMapping.clear                                                                                                                                               
os.MutableMapping.get                                                                                                                                                 
os.MutableMapping.items                                                                                                                                               
os.MutableMapping.keys                                                                                                                                                
os.MutableMapping.pop                                                                                                                                                 
os.MutableMapping.popitem                                                                                                                                             
os.MutableMapping.setdefault                                                                                                                                          
os.MutableMapping.update                                                                                                                                              
os.MutableMapping.values                                                                                                                                              
os.PathLike.__fspath__                                                                                                                                                
os._Environ.__contains__                                                                                                                                              
os._Environ.__delitem__                                                                                                                                               
os._Environ.__eq__                                                                                                                                                    
os._Environ.__getitem__                                                                                                                                               
os._Environ.__init__                                                                                                                                                  
os._Environ.__iter__                                                                                                                                                  
os._Environ.__len__                                                                                                                                                   
os._Environ.__repr__                                                                                                                                                  
os._Environ.__setitem__                                                                                                                                               
os._Environ.clear                                                                                                                                                     
os._Environ.copy                                                                                                                                                      
os._Environ.get                                                                                                                                                       
os._Environ.items                                                                                                                                                     
os._Environ.keys                                                                                                                                                      
os._Environ.pop                                                                                                                                                       
os._Environ.popitem                                                                                                                                                   
os._Environ.setdefault                                                                                                                                                
os._Environ.update                                                                                                                                                    
os._Environ.values                                                                                                                                                    
os._wrap_close.__enter__                                                                                                                                              
os._wrap_close.__exit__                                                                                                                                               
os._wrap_close.__getattr__                                                                                                                                            
os._wrap_close.__init__                                                                                                                                               
os._wrap_close.__iter__                                                                                                                                               
os._wrap_close.close                                                                                                                                                  
os.abc.ABCMeta.__instancecheck__                                                                                                                                      
os.abc.ABCMeta.__new__                                                                                                                                                
os.abc.ABCMeta.__subclasscheck__                                                                                                                                      
os.abc.ABCMeta._abc_caches_clear                                                                                                                                      
os.abc.ABCMeta._abc_registry_clear                                                                                                                                    
os.abc.ABCMeta._dump_registry                                                                                                                                         
os.abc.ABCMeta.register                                                                                                                                               
os.abc.abstractclassmethod.__init__                                                                                                                                   
os.abc.abstractstaticmethod.__init__                                                                                                                                  
os.path._get_sep                                                                                                                                                      
os.path._joinrealpath                                                                                                                                                 
os.path.abspath                                                                                                                                                       
os.path.basename                                                                                                                                                      
os.path.commonpath                                                                                                                                                    
os.path.commonprefix                                                                                                                                                  
os.path.dirname                                                                                                                                                       
os.path.exists                                                                                                                                                        
os.path.expanduser                                                                                                                                                    
os.path.expandvars                                                                                                                                                    
os.path.getatime                                                                                                                                                      
os.path.getctime                                                                                                                                                      
os.path.getmtime                                                                                                                                                      
os.path.getsize                                                                                                                                                       
os.path.isabs                                                                                                                                                         
os.path.isdir                                                                                                                                                         
os.path.isfile                                                                                                                                                        
os.path.islink                                                                                                                                                        
os.path.ismount                                                                                                                                                       
os.path.join                                                                                                                                                          
os.path.lexists                                                                                                                                                       
os.path.normcase                                                                                                                                                      
os.path.normpath                                                                                                                                                      
os.path.realpath                                                                                                                                                      
os.path.relpath                                                                                                                                                       
os.path.samefile                                                                                                                                                      
os.path.sameopenfile                                                                                                                                                  
os.path.samestat                                                                                                                                                      
os.path.split                                                                                                                                                         
os.path.splitdrive                                                                                                                                                    
os.path.splitext                                                                                                                                                      
os.path.genericpath._check_arg_types                                            
os.path.genericpath._splitext                                                   
os.path.genericpath.commonprefix                                                
os.path.genericpath.exists                                                      
os.path.genericpath.getatime                                                    
os.path.genericpath.getctime                                                    
os.path.genericpath.getmtime                                                    
os.path.genericpath.getsize                                                     
os.path.genericpath.isdir                                                       
os.path.genericpath.isfile                                                      
os.path.genericpath.samefile                                                    
os.path.genericpath.sameopenfile                                                
os.path.genericpath.samestat
```

for example there is no [getgrouplis() function](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.getgrouplist) in my output. How can i get list of functions?

Comment: The [doc for `getgrouplist()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.getgrouplist) says that it is available only on unix. Perhaps you're not running this on unix, and perhaps that's the reason why it's missing in the output.

Comment: İ am working on kali linux

Comment: Have you tried importing the function (as further confirmation that it indeed exists in your environment)?

Comment: i have tried just now and it has worked.